# ResetIsDirty on FCKeditor immediately after SetHTML -- Concurrency/timing issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I am using IsDirty to check for changes in my FCKeditor.  Unfortunately, it seems that its functions are asynchronous.

Here is the failing code:

```
var txtObj = $('activities').EstActText1.id;
var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(txtObj);
oEditor.SetHTML(jsonObj.DATA.ESTACTTEXT1.toString());
oEditor.ResetIsDirty();
```

The problem is, SetHTML does not take effect immediately (if you put a check right afterward using GetHTML, it will return what was previously in the textarea).  Thus, ResetIsDirty will run, THEN the HTML will actually be changed, and the dirty flag will be set again.

Is there any way I can force the SetHTML call to complete before continuing?  If not, is there any way (besides a ghetto setTimeout call that will add latency and not necessarily always work) to make sure that the ResetIsDirty will actually take effect after the HTML is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still would be interested in a direct answer, but I'm leaning on the side of that not being very feasible.  It would require something of a sleep function, but JavaScript doesn't go toward that realm.

However, what you're *supposed* to do is handle the FCKeditor_OnComplete event:

```
function FCKeditor_OnComplete( editorInstance )
{
    editorInstance.Events.AttachEvent( 'OnAfterSetHTML', function(){
        editorInstance.ResetIsDirty(); // clean flag to avoid having to save
    } ) ;
    editorInstance.ResetIsDirty(); //clean flag upon initial load as well
}
```

This was placed in a script tag <strike>with defer set</strike>.

Answer (score 0):

I know, the question is not actual, but it may be useful to someone. Try to use:

```
ckeditor = CKEDITOR.instances['Editor_ID'];
ckeditor.setData(lyr_data.lyrics,function(){
    ckeditor.updateElement();
    ckeditor.resetDirty();
});
```